# Make a property bag from a list of keys and values

Tags: kql, azure-data-studio

I have a list containing the keys and another list containing values (obtained from splitting a log line). How can I combine the two to make a proeprty-bag in Kusto?

```
let headers = pack_array("A", "B", "C");
datatable(RawData:string)
[
    "1,2,3",
    "4,5,6",
]
| expand fields = split(RawData, ",")
| expand dict = ???
```

Expected:

```
dict
-----
{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}
{"A": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6}
```

Comment: it may be better if could share the original input (from which you created both arrays) - it could be easier to reach the required dictionary directly from it, without the 2 arrays

Comment: @Yoni thanks. I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option, that uses the combination of:

- `mv-apply`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator
- `pack()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction
- `make_bag()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-bag-aggfunction

```
let keys = pack_array("A", "B", "C");
datatable(RawData:string)
[
    "1,2,3",
    "4,5,6",
]
| project values = split(RawData, ",")
| mv-apply with_itemindex = i key = keys to typeof(string) on (
    summarize dict = make_bag(pack(key, values[i]))
)
```

| values | dict |
| --- | --- |
| [ "1", "2", "3" ] | { "A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3" } |
| [ "4", "5", "6" ] | { "A": "4", "B": "5", "C": "6" } |

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. As I mentioned, the `values` array is extract from a log line. I have updated my questions to clarify the scenario

Comment: the reply was updated according to your update

Comment: Note that it's recommended to use `bag_pack()` instead of `pack()` now since the latter is deprecated. Detail see [bag_pack() - Azure Data Explorer | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction)